# Linux: tunelling an incoming connection

Tags: linux, macos, networking, tunnel

Setup: PC **I** (Ubuntu 11.10, have sudo), Mac **T** (OS X 10.7.2, have sudo), Smart device **S** (barely configurable).

**S** can see to **I** on the local network, but can't see **T**. **I** and **T** can see each other.

There is a program that listens on **T** on port **N**. If someone connects to the program and does not speak its proprietary protocol or does not say anything upon connection, the program shuts down and has to be painfully manually restarted.

**S** must connect to **T** on port **N** and speak to the program. The actual IP **S** connects to is configurable.

I see that I have to set up some kind of relay from **I**, port **N** to **T**, port **N**, but so far I can't wrap my head around out how to do that. Hints are welcome.

A temporary solution (e.g. running ssh with some fancy keys) is preferable to a "permanent" one (like configuring iptables or something), since this is a temporary problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be as simple as this:

```
user@I$ ssh -L I:N:T:N user@T
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up a remote reverse ssh tunnel on "I" to redirect port "N" on itself to port "N" on "T". That way machine S can connect to "T" via "I".

If "N" is eg port 8080, on "I" you can manually set this as

```
ssh -R 8080:IpofT:8080 localhost
```

You may add -N, -f, -n and -v  if needed. See ssh man page.

There are some security issue that may be in the way. Such as if port "N" is a lower range port you need root priviliges, sudo will do.

Also by default many ubuntu servers do not allow external ip redirect. This can be toggled by configuring /etc/ssh/ssh.conf and setting

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

To automate the login you can add your own ssh key on machine "I" to the authorized_keys2 file on "I" as well (as you login via localhost). You can also set up cronjobs to test of the ssh job is running, and to kill/restart it as well.

Alternatively you can set up so that machine "T" logs into machine "I" and tunnels traffic to itself (though not familiar with ssh toolset on osx)

```
     ssh -R 8080:localhost:8080 username@IPofI
```

More information on [port forwarding/tunneling on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding)

Answer (score 1):

Okey, did not notice that you preferred not to use iptables.
Install `socat` and you can create a port forwarder like this on **I**:

```
        "LOCAL/LISTEN"   PORT        "TARGET" DEST : PORT
sudo socat TCP4-LISTEN:N,reuseaddr,fork   TCP4:T:N
```

like

```
sudo socat TCP4-LISTEN:888,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:1.2.3.4:888
```

[See socat man-page for more info](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html)

Here's an iptables way for doing a port Destination NAT (network adress translation).

```
# allow forwarding
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# forward port 888 to host 1.2.3.4:888 
iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp  --dport 888 -j DNAT --to 1.2.3.4:888

# most likely you'll need this to get routing back to your device to work.
# try without this first.
iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

A bit "safer" version where you define the net from where the connections/forwarding is allowed

```
# forward port 888 to host 1.2.3.4:888 allowd from net 2.2.2.0/24
iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -s 2.2.2.0/24  --dport 888 -j DNAT --to 1.2.3.4:888
iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -s 2.2.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```